# STM32F4 custom board, low voltage on reset pin

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, embedded, stm32f4

I designed the following the STM32F407vgt6 custom board for a project.

[image][image][image]

I recently soldered the parts, and powered the board up. I tried programming the board via an STM32F429 Discovery board through the SWD interface and got plenty of errors indicating the MCU was being kept under reset. Then I probed the NRST pin and read a value of 0.40 volts.

The MCU is brand new. All the decoupling capacitors seem to be getting enough voltage(2.9 volts). Regulator works fine too. I am not sure why the NRST pin is at low voltage. Here's the relevant part of the board layout.
[image]

edit1: This is a two-layer board with the top layer being GND+signal and bottom being VDD+signal. I think it's worth mentioning that sometimes the NRST goes down to 0.20 volts. It just varies around 0.20 - 0.40.

I can add a picture of the board if you guys want to see the if there's anything wrong with soldering.
Here are the pictures of the board. Notice that I tried to cut the VCAP line, but it didn't help assuming I successfully cut the line.

[image][image][image]

**update**

I pulled the NRST pin high. After that, I was able to connect and program the MCU via the STM32F429 board through the ST-Link utility. ST-Link utility states that the memory is programmed and verified. I wrote a small program that toggles a few GPIO pins, but when I measure the voltage on those pins I don't see them going high(3V) or low(0V). They just vary around irrelavant values(1.2V, 0.4V, 0.9V etc.).

Comment: If you find that adding an extra resistor pull does not pull up then you may have to consider the consequences of electrostatic discharge damage.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt I'm not saying adding an extra resistor wouldn't help. I'm just saying it shouldn't be needed in the first place.

Comment: If you follow my suggestions you’ll find the root cause

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt Your suggestion is a "fix" for the problem. I don't see how it's gonna help us find the the root cause

Comment: If unused inputs are oscillating , you can fix, if NRST has leakage to ground affected by those inputs, you can fix , if not then it may be destructive leakage (ESD) then you protect the input.  So I disagree. It should tell you the cause not the fix by forensic investigation of these potential issues and future fixes in design.

Comment: What is the resistance between NRST and Ground pin of MCU?

How much is the MCU consumption current now?

Comment: Is the **switch** fine?

Comment: Your power plane is not poured in your picture; hopefully it actually is on your board.  Also make sure that your IC is not rotated 90 degrees on the footprint; it is an easy mistake to make (hint, the writing on the chip *does not* match the orientation on the data sheet, you need to use the pin 1 marker and not the writing)

Comment: (a) "*I can add a picture of the board*" Yes, please - close-up, in-focus photos of the top & bottom of the board. (b) "*It just floats around 0.20 - 0.40.*" I would be careful using the word "floats", as that implies a specific type of situation which hasn't yet been confirmed on your board (as far as I can see). Unless you *know* that pin is floating, a better word might be "varies". (c) If you have access to an oscilloscope, I suggest viewing `NRST` at a reasonable sensitivity (e.g. 0.1V/div, not 1V/div) and seeing how stable it is. (d) Have you also checked Vdd with a 'scope?

Comment: As an aside, I find that the monster part with 100 connections is pretty hard to deal with.  I really prefer breaking the chip down into functional gates in Eagle.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, the top plane is ground and the bottom plane is VDD. I also checked the orientation of the chip and it seems to be correct, as you can see from the pictures.

Comment: @SamGibson I don't have access to a 'scope, unfortunately. I've been probing the NRST pin with a multimeter and it seems to have further dropped down to 0.05 volts. Weird.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately not having a scope prevents you from seeing if whether a multimeter reading of X is really a steady voltage of X, or is actually changing between voltages A and B, with an average of X. That difference can be important with fault-finding something of this complexity. "*I pulled the NRST pin high*" How? Directly to Vdd with a wire, or with a resistor? You said that the GPIO pins "*vary around irrelavant values(1.2V, 0.4V, 0.9V etc.)*". Depending on your program, those measurements with a multimeter *might* be correct, since you said your program *toggles* those GPIO pins.

Comment: @SamGibson I connected the pin directly to a 3.3v source. Doesn't toggling mean toggling between high and low? In that case, why would the values vary depending on my code? Aren't high and low values definite?

Comment: "*I connected the [NRST] pin directly to a 3.3v source*" Yikes! That overrides any possible attempt by the MCU to pull it down & could damage the MCU. I suspect the MCU still tried to pull it down i.e. it still isn't happy. "*Doesn't toggling mean toggling between high and low?*" Yes, but depending on the duty cycle of the toggling *in your code*, the *average* voltage (which is all that a multimeter can show), will not be the voltage of either the logic "high" or the logic "low". That is one reason why the measured voltage depends on your code. I suspect you still have a power-related issue.

Comment: @SamGibson The code toggles the pins then every 3 seconds. So the pins have enough time to go up and down. I will now try adding a resistor in series with NRST. I agree with the idea of having a power-related issue. But what else is there other than the wrong VCAP connection which I tried to cut?

Comment: "*The code toggles the pins then every 3 seconds*" That's the first time that has been mentioned - the word "toggle" could mean switching at 100MHz or 0.0001Hz etc. :-) Agreed that with this new info, voltages around Vdd (2.9V?) and ~0V on a DMM are expected. Unfortunately the images are not in-focus enough (motion blur?) to see the soldering in detail. Also, if you connected `NRST` directly to 3.3V, but Vdd is only 2.9V, then that needs special checking to see if it's allowed. I can't fit all troubleshooting suggestions into a comment here. If you want to use chat here on SE, let me know.

Comment: @SamGibson We can further discuss using the SE chat. Although I'm not sure how to initiate a chat session.

Comment: As discussed: [chat room link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78778)

Answer (score 3):

One possible explanation for `NRST` being low, is that it is being *driven* low by the MCU. That is possible because the STM32 family will drive that external `NRST` pin, when any of the internal reset modules want to reset the MCU. The obvious candidate in this case, is the power reset, if there is a power-related problem. This diagram is taken from the ST AN4488 application note referenced below:

[image: STM32F4 reset circuit]

Since you report that `NRST` is at 0.4V and not an even lower voltage, it seems unlikely that the reset switch itself is the cause, but it's worth checking that.

On a quick first review of your design, I see 2 main areas of concern:

- `BOOT1` is floating

  Although, with `BOOT0` grounded the actual logic level of `BOOT1` doesn't affect the boot mode (as shown in table 6 from ST AN4488 referenced below), I haven't seen a design where `BOOT1` pin is left floating. While I doubt it would cause the specific symptom you report, I would fix it at a valid logic level. FYI the STM32F4 reference designs have 10k resistors in series with both `BOOT` pins, before they are then pulled high or low externally, as required.
- `VCAP1` and `VCAP2` are connected

  This is my main concern. I haven't seen the internal MCU architecture to show the difference between these two pins (which decouple the internal 1.2V power domain of the MCU core), but notice that in the ST "[AN4488: Getting started with STM32F4xxxx MCU hardware development](http://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00115714.pdf)" document, these two pins are each *separately* connected to a 2.2uF capacitor - and not, as shown in your schematic & PCB, connected together and then jointly connected to two 2.2uF capacitors.

  Some of the text about this in the above document is a little ambiguous, but the reference schematic on PDF page 34 is clear about how those pins should be used:

  [image: VCAP connections from STM32F4 reference schematic]

  Looking at your PCB layout, it seems that you can just cut the track linking your capacitors `C11` and `C13` to perform the necessary separation. Also, make sure you are using the specified type of capacitors, if you aren't doing so already.

  My hypothesis is that this incorrect connection between the two `VCAP` pins, might be causing the MCU to keep its internal power reset asserted, which is what you are measuring as the logic low (0.4V) on the `NRST` pin.

---

I recommend reading the whole of that document, including section 9.3 titled "MCU does not work properly", which may give you more ideas of areas to investigate.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that VCAP connection part when designing the board. That's an obvious design flaw of my board. Thanks for pointing that out. I will try to cut the line between the caps and see if it helps. For what it's worth, I did go through the above document during the design phase, but somehow missed some details.

Answer (score 0):

You probably require a pull-up resistor - 10K or so from the reset pin to Vcc - to ensure that the reset pin is High when the reset button is not pressed.

Comment: This is not really required since the NRST pin is internally pulled high. Reference design does not include a pull-up resistor for the pin either.

Comment: If unused inputs are initialized,  they should not be floating.